# Transitive joins in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join, transitivity

What is the best way to achieve a transitive join in postgresql? Currently, I want to do a full outer join for tables, a, b, and c. My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b
ON a."ID" = b."ID"
FULL OUTER JOIN c
ON a."ID" = c."ID"
```

I'm running into an issue where some records that match in table B and table C are showing up in different rows in the query output, and I realized that it must be because I have not explicitly joined tables B and C. What is the best way to write a "transitive" query where a=b, a=c, and b=c?
Here is an example of my current output. Right now, when a matching ID exists for just tables B and C, I get 2 different rows:

| A ID | B ID | C ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 32 | null |
| 35 | 35 | 35 |
| 36 | null | 36 |
| null | **42** | null |
| null | null | **42** |

Here is my desired output:

| A ID | B ID | C ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 32 | null |
| 35 | 35 | 35 |
| 36 | null | 36 |
| null | **42** | **42** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `using`:

```
SELECT *
FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN
     b
     USING ("ID") FULL OUTER JOIN
     c
     USING ("ID");
```

If in your real example, the columns have different names:

```
SELECT *
FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN
     b
     ON b.id = a.id FULL OUTER JOIN
     c
     ON c.id = COALESCE(b.id, a.id);
```

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly! I appreciate your help.